# find a way to display data from ParseQuery In a TextView or some other widget

Tags: android, parse-platform

How do I display the data I received from parse Query in my app? I Tried using a text view  here is the code:.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
  TextView TV;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Parse.initialize(this, "yJLMQIyh7aDmek749GAPqFX1lnd49gyt3onU38fx", "0tA39RGLy4g1QPpgW7vNsgxKaoytFuMAzJutrWbS");


        TV=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1); 

        final ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
        gameScore.put("score", 1337);
        gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");
        gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
        gameScore.put("score", 50000);
        gameScore.put("playerName", "Alexandrina");
        gameScore.put("cheatMode", true);

        gameScore.saveInBackground();

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
        query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
          public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
              // object will be your game score



            } else {
              // something went wrong
            }
          }



          int score = gameScore.getInt("score");
          String playerName = gameScore.getString("playerName");
          boolean cheatMode = gameScore.getBoolean("cheatMode");
```

How do isisplay the "playerName"? for example?

Answer (score 0):

You should write query to find the game score you want. Then get the parseObject. Via "TV.setText(gameScore.getString("playerName")); "  you can show your user name.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query= ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
    query.whereEqualTo("score", 1337);

try {
    ParseObject gameScore = userData.getFirst();
    TV.setText(gameScore.getString("playerName"));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    return null;
}
```

or as you write;

```
if (e == null) {
    TV.setText(object.getString("playerName")); // add this
}
```

....